# PHP 7 execute procedure from Mysql 5.7 Error

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, pdo

I have a problem with execute stored procedure in PHP.

**my procedure is :**

```
create procedure test_procedure()
  BEGIN
     select yf_f_get_msg(-2);
  END
```

**my function is :**

```
create function `yf_f_get_msg`(`p_sql_state` int(11))
  returns text
BEGIN
    declare specialty condition for sqlstate '45000';
    if p_sql_state < 0 then
        signal specialty set message_text = 'It is just error';
    end if;
    return 1;
END
```

My procedure execute function and my function return exception (signal error).

**php code**

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', null);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}

$sth = $dbh->prepare('call test_procedure()');
$sth->execute();
```

So I cant load page in my browser.
http://joxi.net/brRjzzWCpvbYr1

If use mysqli connection you get like this http://joxi.net/a2XDzzRizYY62g

Answer (score 0):

If use **set @g  = (select yf_f_get_msg(-2));** in procedure it will work.

```
create procedure test_procedure()
  BEGIN
    set @g = (select yf_f_get_msg(-2));
  END
```